# How to fetch multiple conditional queries in Apollo Client React?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, react-hooks, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm using Apollo Client, and for fetching queries I'm using `useQuery` from the package `@apollo/react-hooks`.

I would like to accomplish the following:

### List of Steps:

**Step 1:** Fetch a query `stage`

```
const GetStage = useQuery(confirmStageQuery, {
  variables: {
    input: {
      id: getId.id
    }
  }
});
```

**Step 2:** Based on the response that we get from `GetStage`, we would like to switch between 2 separate queries

```
if (!GetStage.loading && GetStage.data.getGame.stage === "Created") {
  Details = useQuery(Query1, {
    variables: {
      input: {
        id: getId.id
      }
    }
  });
} else if (!GetStage.loading && GetStage.data.getGame.stage === "Confirmed") {
  Details = useQuery(Query2, {
    variables: {
      input: {
        id: getId.id
      }
    }
  });
}
```

**Step 3:** Also when the page loads every time, I'm re-fetching the data.

```
useEffect(() => {
  //Fetch for Change in the Stage
  GetStage.refetch();

  //Fetch for Change in the Object
  if (Details) {
    Details.refetch();
    if (Details.data) {
      setDetails(Details.data.getGame);
    }
  }
});
```

---

### Problem?

> Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.
>
> Details.data is undefined

So how can we call multiple async queries in Apollo Client?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As Philip said, you can't conditionally call hooks. However conditionally calling a query is very common, so Apollo allows you to skip it using the `skip` option:

```
const { loading, error, data: { forum } = {}, subscribeToMore } = useQuery(GET_FORUM, {
  skip: !forumId,
  fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network',
  variables: { id: forumId },
});
```

The hook is called, but the query isn't. That's a lot simpler and clearer than using a lazy query for your use case in my opinion.

Comment: its good way, but when you want to fetch first or second query lazy hook is best way to solve this problem, in my opinion.

Answer (score 6):

[The rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) say you can't conditionally call hooks, whenever you find yourself in a situation where you want to use an if/else around a hook you're probably on the wrong track.

What you want to do here is to use a [lazyQuery](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#executing-queries-manually) for everything that's "optional" or will be fetched later - or for queries that depend on the result of another query.

Here's a quick example (probably not complete enough to make your entire code work):

```
// This query is always called, use useQuery
const GetStage = useQuery(confirmStageQuery, {
  variables: {
    input: {
      id: getId.id
    }
  }
});

const [fetchQuery1, { loading1, data1 }] = useLazyQuery(Query1);
const [fetchQuery2, { loading2, data2 }] = useLazyQuery(Query2);

// Use an effect to execute the second query when the data of the first one comes in

useEffect(() => {
  if (!GetStage.loading && GetStage.data.getGame.stage === "Created") {
    fetchQuery1({variables: {
     input: {
        id: getId.id
      }
    }})
  } else if (!GetStage.loading && GetStage.data.getGame.stage === "Confirmed") {
    fetchQuery2({variables: {
     input: {
        id: getId.id
      }
    }})
  } 
}, [GetState.data, GetStage.loading])
```